# Is is possible to reference mapbox maki-icons in plotly scattermapbox?

Tags: plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

It appears that the list of icons available for scattermapbox is limited. I am trying to use icons from the list here: https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/, however, it appears that some are not available.

I checked the plotly scattermapbox documentation and it looks like they should be work: https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scattermapbox-marker-symbol. So, I am not sure what's missing.

```
# Property Location
   data.append({
                "type": "scattermapbox",
                "lat": [Lat],
                "lon": [Long],
                "hovertext": price,
                "text": "Asking rent ${} SF/YR".format(price),
                "textfont": {"size": 22},
                "textposition": "top-right",
                "showlegend": False,
                "hoverinfo": "text",
                "mode": "text+markers",
                "marker": {
                    "symbol": "industry",
                    "size": 28,
                    "opacity": 0.7
                    }
                }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but the industry icon is not included in the mapbox styles (see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles).